# highchart click event and export menu

Tags: highcharts, event-handling, export

I use the click event in order to zoom in a chart. But this event is fired even when you click on an item in the export menu (such as "download PNG image").

Is there a method to tell if you clicked on the export menu? This would allow not to do anything in this case.

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle?